# advantage database server current database name

Tags: sybase, advantage

How to get current database name in advantage database server? I don't know which query will answer this question. I have tried `select top 10 * from system.logins` but I got below error message:

> Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = HY000;   NativeError = 5004;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL][ASA] Either ACE could not find the specified file, or you do not have sufficient rights to access the file. Table name: logins  AdsCommand query execution failed.

Comment: What does `select d.name from master..sysdatabases d, master..sysprocesses p where d.dbid=p.dbid and p.spid=@@spid` return?

Answer (score 0):

In Advantage/SQLAnywhere, the database names are stored in [sysdbspaces](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/sysdbspace-system-view.html)

To access the name of the database you are currently in use the `db_name()` function.

```
select db_name()
```